# SQL - ORDER BY Clause (Multiple data in 1 column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

can anyone help me out with this problem?

How to Query this:

[image: WHAT SHOULD BE THE RESULT TABLE]

My Query:

```
  `SELECT TOP 1000 [WireID]
  ,[PadNo]
  ,[Pattern]
  ,[Tester]
  FROM FROM [WLSystem].[dbo].[TblR8Pure] 
  ORDER BY LEN(Tester), Tester ASC`
```

RESULT:

[image: MY QUERY RESULT]

Comment: Please include sample data in textual format and not like images.

Comment: Storing values as csv is no good db design. You should Change it

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos in the image presents the sample result.

Comment: Agree with @Jens. And this whole ordering does not make sense if you have lists like in your 3rd row: "42, 128, 28". If you can have a lower value 28 after the starting value 42 in the list, your order just won't be what you expected probably. At least it does not make to much sense for me.

Comment: What SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: @gofr1 MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the correct answer =)

MS SQL:

[Correct Answer MsSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD4vi.png)

MYSQL:

[Correct Answer MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djufn.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to get first item from comma separated string:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
        [WireID],
        [PadNo],
        [Pattern],
        [Tester]    
FROM [WLSystem].[dbo].[TblR8Pure]
ORDER BY CAST(
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(';',[Tester])-1 < 0 THEN REPLACE([Tester],CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')
            ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Tester],1,CHARINDEX(';',[Tester])-1),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'')
            END
             as int)
```

But the best way is to normalize your data and get rid of comma separated values in 1 column.

Comment: Hi @gofr1 I tried to execute your query by the lower value like 40 is the middle. try to look at my edited post. thanks

Comment: I add cast(... as int) in order by statement. Give this query a try

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '100
' to data type int.

Comment: Or my, you got spaces... Add rtrim and ltrim. See my edit to an answer

Comment: If you got ; instead of , as were mentioned in your question previously, change ',' on ';' in CHARINDEX part

Comment: Sorry but I got the same error.  Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '100' to data type int.

Comment: Hi @gofr1 I already change the ',' to ';' see the edited problem above. thanks

Comment: I bet there are `line feed`s and `carriage return` in `[Tester]` try new query. if this wont work try to change `CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)` with `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [WireID]
  ,[PadNo]
  ,[Pattern]
  ,[Tester]
  FROM FROM [WLSystem].[dbo].[TblR8Pure] 
  ORDER BY Tester ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from  the facts that this type of dating storing is bad design. This query will sort the result by the first 3 numbers of the tester column. This works by using stuff to delete all remaining characters.

```
  SELECT TOP 1000 [WireID]
  ,[PadNo]
  ,[Pattern]
  ,[Tester]
  FROM FROM [WLSystem].[dbo].[TblR8Pure] 
  ORDER BY STUFF(Tester,4,99,'') ASC
```

Comment: Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The stuff function requires 4 argument(s).

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the '' to replace the remaining characters with nothing can you try again.

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure you include test data in text format. It is much easier to answer. You also receive more valuable answers.*

Simpified test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TblR8Pure
(
    [No] int,
    PadNo varchar(10),
    Pattern int,
    Jumper varchar(100)
)

INSERT #TblR8Pure VALUES
(3, '4_39', 85, '40'),
(3, '4_45', 79, '225 ; 219'),
(3, '4_40', 79, '418 ; 566'),
(3, '4_46', 79, '229 ; 355 ; 320'),
(3, '4_44', 79, '234 ; 362 ; 318'),
(3, '4_55', 79, '1000 ; 1')
```

Here are solution rules:

1. Records are sorted by smallest Jumper found in semicolon separated value, converted to int (XML part)
2. Values can have white characters (LTRIM,RTRIM)
3. If two equal Jumpers are found, records are ordered by 2nd, 3rd etc (PIVOT and ORDER part, here limited to 5 fields).

And here is the solution:

```
SELECT [No], PadNo, Pattern, Jumper FROM
(
    SELECT [No], PadNo, Pattern, Jumper, Rec, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rec ORDER BY Value) R FROM
    (
        SELECT [No], PadNo, Pattern, Jumper, Rec, CONVERT(int, RTRIM(LTRIM(R.value('.', 'varchar(10)')))) Value FROM
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) Rec, CONVERT(xml,'<a>'+REPLACE(Jumper, ';', '</a><a>')+'</a>') X FROM #TblR8Pure) T
        CROSS APPLY T.X.nodes('a') T2(R)
    ) T
) T
PIVOT
(MAX(Value) FOR R IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) P
ORDER BY [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the ..

[Best Answer:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8kne.png)

REFER SITE: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/151246/Sql-Order-By/